# How to read multiples files from a compressed file?

Tags: r, csv

I would like to know how to read multiple file from a zipped folder ("test2.zip") in R.

I wrote the below-code which works only when there is only one file in the zipped folder. I need to know how to get all the files/multiples file from a zipped folder and make it readable in R.
Different .CSV files required as data-frames.

```
test5 <- read.csv(unzip("path/test2.zip", files = NULL, list = FALSE, 
                  overwrite = TRUE, junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", 
                  unzip = "internal",setTimes = FALSE))
```

Further when I try to put the zip file which has two .csv files it gives the error

> Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

How to read all the csv files included inside the compressed file?

Comment: For example, `lapply(unzip("path/test2.zip"), read.csv)` should return you a list with your csvs.

Comment: @lukeA thanks
 t2<-lapply(unzip("path/test2.zip"), read.csv) ir returns as Value need it as seperate Data frames

Comment: You should have seperate data frames - they are just packed in a list. For example, `t2[[1]]` should give you access to the first data frame in that list. If you want to explode the list, you can do `names(t2) <- paste0("df", seq(t2)); list2env(t2, globalenv())`.

Comment: @lukeA thanks for quick response.
Just a quick check is there a way to get the "df" named the same as it is inside the zip file?
For example if the .zip file has file named test1 and test2 and when unzipped it names the datafame the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. First, I zip 2 sample files for demo purpose:

```
write.csv(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2), tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
write.csv(data.frame(x = 11:12, y = 11:12), tf2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
zip(zipfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), files = c(tf1, tf2))
```

Now, unzip...

```
fns <- unzip(zipfile, junkpaths = TRUE, exdir = tempdir())
list2env(setNames(lapply(fns, read.csv, row.names = 1), basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(fns))), globalenv())
```

The data frames are stored in variables, which have been named by the filenames.